# Any way to limit the input arguments of a FastAPI handler into several specified options?

Tags: python-asyncio, fastapi

I'm wondering if there's someway could let me easily deal with input arguments and limit them into several values in FASTAPI.

For example if I got a hello-world handler here:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get(/)
async def root(name:str):
    return {"user_name_is": name}
```

And what I'd like to achieve is , to let user can only input one of the following names as parameter [`Bob` ,`Jack`] , other names are all illegal.

It's not complicated to write some further check code to achieve the expected result:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get(/)
async def root(name:str):
    if name in ['Bob' , 'Jack']:
         return {"user_name_is": name}
    else:
         raise HTTPException(status_code=403)
```

However it's still not easy enough to write codes especially when there're lots of input arguments need to deal with. I'm wondering if there's a way I can use type-hints and pydantic to achieve the same result?

Didn't find much information in doc, need help , thanks.

=======

btw , if there's also chance I need to get a list of input prameters , is there any way to check them all , like the following code,?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import List

app = FastAPI()

@app.get(/)
async def root(names:List[str]):
    for name in names:
        if name not in ['Bob','Jack']:
            raise ...
    # else ,check passed
    return {"user_name_is": name}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Enum` for it: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/?h=enum#predefined-values

```py
from enum import Enum

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI


class Names(str, Enum):
    Bob = "Bob"
    Jack = "Jack"


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root(name: Names):
    return {"user_name_is": name}
```

Answer (score 11):

I know this question has already an answer accepted but I feel that the cleanest way is to use the `Literal` typing like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Literal

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/{name}")
async def root(name: Literal["Bob", "Jack"]):
    return {"user_name_is": name}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, maybe that's the best practice

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for Pydantic's `@validator`

See: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from typing import List
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends


app = FastAPI()


class Names(BaseModel):
    names: List[str]

    @validator("names", pre=True, always=True)
    def check_allowed_names(cls, v):
        allowed_names = ["Billie", "Joe"]
        for name in v:
            if name not in allowed_names:
                raise ValueError(f"Name {name} is not allowed")

        return v


@app.post("/")
async def root(names: Names):
    return {"user_name_is": names.names}
```